# How to get data from list of dict on basis of string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/asd/file.csv'},
        {'name': 'root/folder1/bsd/file.csv'}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3/new.csv'}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3'}]
```

I want to take this list and pare it down to include only files that have a certain extension and exist in the shallowest folder in the list. That is, if a path has two `/` in it, and all other paths have at least two, then filter out all paths that have more than two. If the smallest number of slashes is three, then filter out anything with more than three.

This is what I started with:

```
for path in data:
    if path.get('name').endswith('.exe') or path.endswith('.csv'):
       path_count = len(re.findall('/', path)) 
       path.update({'path_count': path_count})
```

Now I will check minimum count by again applying a for loop. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why not store the names in a simple list?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but you can leverage list comprehensions and their filters to get a list of objects that meet some arbitrary requirements:

```
extensions = {"exe", "csv"}

def ext_filter(path: str) -> bool:
    ext = path.split(".")[-1]
    return ext and ext in extensions

def slash_filter(path: str, count: int) -> bool:
    return ext_filter(path) and count == path.count("/")

slash_count = min((path.get("name", "").count("/") for path in data if ext_filter(path.get("name"))))

valid_paths = [path for path in data if slash_filter(path.get("name", ""), slash_count)]
```

Comment: hi sir , thanks for answer but I want to get records which have minimum slashes . and minimum will be counted dynamically

Comment: @newbiee Are you defining the minimum, or are you saying you're looking for the paths with the fewest number of slashes?

Comment: sir   looking for the paths with the fewest number of slashes in path like if the fewest count is 3 then all paths with 3 slashes . and if 2 then all paths with 2 slashes

Comment: getting wrong results sir . getting  minimum  slash_count even when there is no extension  . I want minimum path with extension

Comment: Updated. Also, just as a friendly suggestion - dropping the 'sir' might serve you better. It sounds presumptuous in text, especially when it's dropped into a fragmented sentence, which probably is working against your intent to show respect.

Comment: Thanks , I don't have any senior to guide so that's why was giving you respect . Sorry if it sound this way. thanks for help it's working

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/asd/file.csv'},
        {'name': 'root/folder1/bsd/file.csv'}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3/new.csv'}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3'}]


min_count = min(list(
                    # mapping lambda count on the pathnames in 
                    map(lambda x: list(x.values()).pop().count('/'), 
                    # the generator expression for dictionaries in the list
                    (d for d in data))))

for el in data:
    for key, item in el.items():
        if item.count('/') == min_count and item.endswith(('.exe', '.csv')):
            print(f'key {key} item {item}')
                  
                  key name item root/folder1/asd/file.csv
                  key name item root/folder1/bsd/file.csv
```

Comment: hi sir , thanks for answer but I want to get records which have minimum slashes . and minimum will be counted dynamically

Comment: @newbiee. Ok. I have added a line to count the min_count.

Comment: for me still showing   item.count('/') == 3

Comment: @ I may have not saved the changes then. Now the min count it there. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

If time of running the code matters you can do it in one go, controlling that you include only shortest paths.
For example:

```
results = []
for item in data:
    path = item['name']
    if path.endswith('exe') or path.endswith('csv'):
        path_count = path.count('/')
        if len(results) == 0:
            results.append(path)
            n = path_count
        elif path_count == n:
            results.append(path)
        elif path_count < n:
            results = [path]
            n = path_count
```

Comment: Doing it in one pass is not going to be any faster than doing it in two passes, if you double the number of operations in the first pass, which you will probably do here. In particular, in the worst case you end up writing every element in the original list to the result list, which will take more time than finding only those elements that need to be written out.